# Can i edit the external XML file through AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to edit the external XML file through only AS3. Please any one help me.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flash Player and the XML is on a server then the answer is NO. This would be a lack of security as a client could directly edit something that resides on a server.

It is possible to load the XML, change values in it and then send it back to a PHP file that dumps it into a file, again, with the fore mentioned risks.